# Can I create the C++ threads with the same name?

Tags: c++, c++11, thread-safety, threadpool

everyone.
I have written the code as follow:

```
std::thread t1(cmdThread);
t1.detach();

for (int n = 0; n < tCount; n++)
{
    std::thread t1(sendThread,n+1);
    t1.detach();
}
```

CmdThread and sendThread are different.
All the threads named t1, but they work well as usual. That confused me.
In the for loop, I want to creat 4 threads.
Does C++ allow the user to create the same name thread and the threads can also detach well?

Comment: maybe you should have a look at [nested scopes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/scope#Nested_scopes)

Comment: I have no clue what you mean with _thread name_, `t1` is a variable symbol, which is completely irrelevant for the code finally excecuted. If you want to see something that identifies a particular thread uniquely you should have a look at [`std::thread::get_id()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/get_id).

Comment: Yeah,man.I have used the function, std::this_thread::get_id(), in the function,sendThread. The get_id shows that there are 4 different threads in the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I create the C++ threads with the same name?

In C++, there is no concept of a thread having a name.

> All the threads named t1

`t1` is a variable. The type of the variable is `std::thread` which is a thread wrapper. `t1` is local to the loop body, and therefore the variable names a new object in each iteration.

In its initialisation, the thread wrapper named by variable `t1` creates a thread that is then owned by the wrapper. The thread created by the wrapper has no name. When the thread is detached from `t1`, the wrapper no longer owns a thread and the detached thread has no owner. At the end of the iteration, the thread wrapper is destroyed. In the next iteration, this process is repeated.

You can do what you did in the example program.

Comment: Thanks Sir.  "std::thread t1(cmdThread); t1.detach();" When the t1 first time is detached. The t1 is deleted and the cmdThread thread is create. Next the the program running the line "std::thread t1(sendThread,n+1); t1.detach();" , a new t1 is created. Then the t1 is detached and delete .Finally, n++ steps into the next for loop and repeat create t1 and detach it. Is it?

Comment: @AdamPengC There is no "cmdThread thread". A thread is created, and the function `cmdThread` is called in that thread. And automatic objects are not "deleted". They are destroyed when they go out of scope. Furthermore, the `t1` in the outer scope outlives the `t1` in the loop body. Otherwise yes.